# Library em C com auto checksum

Tags: c, segurança, android-ndk, checksum

Estou criando uma biblioteca/library para o Android em C, e gostaria de saber como faço para que ela exiba seu próprio `checksum`, assim, caso sofra alguma "*alteração*" depois de compilada, o `checksum` ira mudar.

Comment: Não sei se tem algo especifico pra android, mas eu tenho um caso desses numa aplicação minha pra outra plataforma, que me fez parar pra pensar um pouco. O checksum muda se você colocar o valor dele dentro da própria aplicação. Tem umas propriedades do CRC32 que até dariam pra fazer um "desconto" no cálculo, mas a solução que eu encontrei foi um pouco diferente, foi colocar o checksum e a posição dele no código, assim o código "pula" a própria posição no cálculo de conferência. O cuidado que tem que ter é que assim fica fácil alguem alterar o código + o valor.

Comment: Acho que entendi o que você quis dizer, difícil vai ser eu conseguir isso sozinho. É de rachar a cuca :) É, tem esse porem de mudarem o código, não duvido dessa possibilidade.

Comment: Você poderia simplesmente adicionar um CRC32 nos ultimos 4 bytes do executável, mas ai fica muito mais facil mexerem. Se for uma aplicação online fica muito mais fácil o CRC ficar no seu servidor. A aplicação conecta, passa o CRC32 dela, e a versão, e o servidor simplesmente diz se ta certo ou não.

Comment: Andei pensando, sera que usando um `fopen` abrindo a própria library e checando o `md5` não seria uma possível solução?

Comment: Eu prefiro CRC pra essas coisas. MD5 é lento e não adequado para dados extensos. De qualquer forma, cai no problema inicial que eu comentei: como é que você armazena esse MD5 na aplicação depois, sem alterar o próprio valor?

Comment: Essa é a questão, não armazenar, para evitar que ele seja alterado, por isso ele deve ser pego dinamicamente, apenas o servidor tem esse valor, para a checagem. Infelizmente não tenho cacique pra criar um código assim, mas já achei um resta saber se é isso mesmo que ele faz, pegar o CRC32.

Comment: CRC32 costuma ter implementação simples em qualquer linguagem. é só ir lendo o arquivo aos pedaços, e realimentar a função. Geralmente as implementações permitem CRC32( string, valor anterior ) para você não precisar ler o arquivo todo na memória. Vai calculando aos pedaços, e usando o ultimo cálculo como valor anterior.